# Why doesn't Brother HL 2130 printer work on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, printing, brother

I'm facing problems with Brother HL 2130 printer on Ubuntu 13.04. It doesn't print anything and all the loaded papers flow away at the same time from the box.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

ok, now I got things working. If you add the driver to your system, select the "Brother HL-2140 Foomatic/hl250" instead of the Postcript driver. Ubuntu's page of supported Brother drivers lists the HL1250 as full supported, wherefore I considered this to be a try. It worked at lest for me.

Best!

Comment: Wondering why this wasn't discovered and/or resolved in the QA process.

Comment: This solution worked for me!

Comment: This also worked for my actual Brother HL-2140, which doesn't choose the `.../hl1250` driver by default. After the printer was installed, going into the properties and changing to that driver did it on Ubuntu 13.10. Thanks!

Comment: This answer has saved me 3 times now, ta